# How to display my nav bar on img tag which I am using as background?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am new to HTML/CSS and I am trying to create my portfolio.
I will let the code simply speak for itself. Please note I am only copying the code which I think is relevant to this issue; if you need additional code, let me know.

HTML Code:-

```
<div class="NeroCorp">
        <ul id="nav-bar">
            <li><a href="#AboutMe">About Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#WhatIDo">WHAT I DO</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Hobbies">HOBBIES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Work">WORK</a></li>
        </ul>
        <img src="Images/sea.jpg">
        <div class="NeroTitle">NERO CORP DEVELOPMENT</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="SubTitleHolder">
            <h2 class="SubTitle">ABOUT ME</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="SubTitleHolder info1">
            <p><a id="AboutMe">
                TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
                TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
                TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
                TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
                TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT<br><br>
                TITLETITLETITLETITLETITLETITLETITLETITLETITLETITLETITLETITLETITLETITLE
                TITLETITLETITLETITLETITLETITLETITLETITLETITLETITLETITLETITLETITLETITLE
            </a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS Code:-

```
#nav-bar{
    text-align: center;
}

#nav-bar li{
    display: inline;
}

#nav-bar a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 30px;
}

body{
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center

}
```

This is what I have currently.
[image: This is what I have currently]

This is what I want to achieve.
[image]

So basically, I want to place my navigation over the image tag which I am using as my background. I've tried using position absolute on my Nav Bar but it doesn't let me center my nav bar. I can understand it's poor practice to use img tag for background images but I don't know how to overcome this. I am using img tag for background because I am going to have number of different images acting as background as different section of the website. 
Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's better to use `background-image` and you can always insert the image url in the HTML like you did with `img` so that you can have different section with different backgrounds. Then it will easier to handle with CSS and you can for example add an overlay above it using pseudo element to control the contrast:

```css
#nav-bar {
  text-align: center;
}

#nav-bar li {
  display: inline;
}

#nav-bar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 30px;
}

body {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center
}

.back {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  /* Control the image*/
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  /**/
}

.back .NeroCorp {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height:100%;
}

.NeroTitle {
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom:50px;
}


/* Overlay above the image */

.back:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="back" style="background-image:url(https://lorempixel.com/1000/600/)">
  <div class="NeroCorp">
    <ul id="nav-bar">
      <li><a href="#AboutMe">About Me</a></li>
      <li><a href="#WhatIDo">WHAT I DO</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Hobbies">HOBBIES</a></li>
      <li><a href="#Work">WORK</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="NeroTitle">NERO CORP DEVELOPMENT</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="SubTitleHolder">
    <h2 class="SubTitle">Section 1</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="SubTitleHolder info1">
    <p><a id="AboutMe">
                TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
                TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
                TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
                TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
                TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT<br><br>
               
            </a></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="SubTitleHolder">
    <h2 class="SubTitle">Section 2</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="SubTitleHolder info1">
    <p><a id="AboutMe">
                TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
                TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
                TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
                TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT
                TEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXTTEXT<br><br>
               
            </a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want the "Section 1" stuff or in this case the Div "SubTitleHolder info1" to be on any background. I just want to simply place my navigation bar, the title "NERO CORP DEVELOPMENT" on the background and the rest below it. I've tried your idea but how can I keep the full size of the background?

Comment: @Nero updated my answer ;) and yes you can keep the background full size by adjust the size of `back` and also adjusting the property of the background

Comment: Works great, a little hard to understand but giving me the desired result

Comment: @Nero tell me what's hard and i will explain you ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your case it looks like you can just add position: absolute for nav-bar.
 Something like:

```
#nav-bar{
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
}
```

As I understand, you wrote a similar style for #NeroTitle.
But your image will have different height for different devices. And I think it's better to move your background image in background with background-size: cover. Then you'll be able to control #NeroCorp block height.
Also the best way to learn how to make something you have on your screen is to read code. You always can open Developer Tool and check css for elements you want to use for your site.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have a few options here:

## Make you nav-bar absolutely positioned

This is the standard way I'd say. You mentioned this and said you had problems centering it? That should not be a problem as long as you don't forget to make it stretch the entire width:

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div>This is centered</div>
```

## Make your image(-container) absolutely positioned

You can do the same for the container, but you might need to cheat a bit if you want something underneath it.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

.bg-img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div style="color:blue;">Now you can put anything over it</div>

<img src="http://www.placecage.com/1000/800" class="bg-img">
```

## Actually use background-image and switch it out using js

You also mentioned, you wanted to switch out the background, so why not do that using js. However you can't animate them, which is why I mentioned this last.

```js
(function() {
  const images = [
    "http://www.placecage.com/500/500",
    "http://www.placecage.com/500/1000",
    "http://www.placecage.com/1000/500",
    "http://www.placecage.com/1000/1000"
  ];
  let i = 0;

  function nextBg() {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + images[i] + ")";
    ++i;
    if (i === images.length)
      i = 0;
  }

  nextBg();
  setInterval(() => {
    nextBg();
  }, 5000);
})();
```